# Regex - how to get string between two character or only one?

Tags: regex

I need to select the SKU of the following products:

```
Geladeira Brastemp Inverse 422 Litros - BRE50NR
Lava-Louças Brastemp Ative! 8 Serviços - BLF08AS - 110V
```

How to I create a unique regex that can get the codes from each of this strings?

The code on the first string is BRE50NR, the second woudl be BLF08AS. Note that there is a '-' a the begining of the second string in the word Lava-louça.

Comment: Are all of your SKUs exactly 7 characters?  Will those two inputs be representative of all of your inputs?  ie: preceeded by `text - ` and optionally proceeded by ` - text` or can `text - text - sku` or `text - sku - text - text` occur, for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, with a lookahaed:

```
(?<= - )\w+
```

And use exactly what is matched.
If the code has no lowercase, then you can even use:

```
(?<= - )[A-Z0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\d+ *\S+ *- *(\S+)
```

And grab captured group #1

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vM1xR3/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=[ ]-[ ])\b[A-Z0-9]{7}\b
```